# Take SQL average with a virtual default column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'd like to take an average of reviews.rating, but apply a default rating of 4. Users will start with a rating of 4, then if someone leaves them a 3, their rating will be calculated as 3.5.

Currently, I'm only using a simple AVG:

```
SELECT AVG("reviews"."rating") AS average_rating
FROM "reviews" 
WHERE "reviews"."user_id" = :user_id
```

Is there a way I can select a virtual value of 4 and then have it be included in the AVG calculation? I'm using Rails and PG if it matters, but would like to keep the calculation in the database for speed (instead of pulling out all of the data and doing the average in Ruby).

Comment: can there be multiple ratings for a user? if so, should 4 be added to each of the ratings?

Comment: Yes, multiple reviews can be given per user, and the 4 should be added once.

Comment: `(sum(x) + 4) / (count(*) + 1)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the average yourself:

```
SELECT (sum(rating)+ 4.0)/(count(rating)+ 1) AS average_rating
FROM reviews
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Should be `...count(rating)...` to avoid `NULL` values (if any).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat it like everybody has a single virtual review of rating 4, then you can `UNION` their actual ratings with that value.

```
SELECT AVG( rating ) AS average_rating FROM (
  SELECT reviews.rating FROM reviews WHERE reviews.user_id = :user_id
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS rating
)
```

This will also cause someone with no reviews to have an average of 4, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: Should be `UNION ALL`